# Creating multiple ggplots with dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

After creating a plot matrix using `GGally::ggpairs()`, I would like to store the individual scatter plots for later use.

Here is my current code:

```
# load necessary package
library(GGally) # loads `ggplot2` 
library(magrittr) # allows for the use of `%>%`

# create a matrix of plots
mtcars %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggpairs(columns = 1:7)

# how do I automate this process?
P1 <- ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = hp)) + 
        geom_point()
P2 <- ggplot(aes(x = drat, y = hp)) + 
        geom_point()
P3 <- ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = qsec)) + 
        geom_point()
```

I'm getting an error that says the data must be a dataframe. I tried to specify the data from the `na.omit()` pipe using a `.` but I received the same result.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some or all of `UN3` to make this question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In your code example, the pipe ends at the `ggpairs` line. In the next 3 lines, you are not passing anything to the `data = ` argument (perhaps you meant `data = mtcars` ?). The intention of the code is not clear.

Comment: @neilfws apologies I tried to shrink the code down to make it more readable, but forgot to make a few changes. I think the problem is that the pipe operator stops providing output after the first ggpairs function. Am I understanding you correctly? Is there a way to reference the data in each ggplot?

Comment: As neilfws noted, it's not clear what you intend to do after passing the dataset to `ggpairs()`. The output from that is a `gg` object, not a data frame. Do you mean you want to overlay different `geom_point()` layers to it? (If so, do include a sketch of what your desired output looks like.) Do you simply want to pass your dataset to `ggplot()` and add three different `geom_point()` layers? (If so, what's `ggpairs()` doing in the code?)

Comment: @Z.Lin my intention is to create a `ggpairs()` object and create the `ggplot` objects independently for use later. Is this possible? Or perhaps it is asking too much. I've made a few more edits for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

## Overview

I condensed all the separate `ggplot(...)` calls into one custom function: `ScatterPlot()`.

Then I created another custom function `ManyScatterPlots()` - which uses [`purrr::map()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) - that stores the individual scatter plot for each particular column in `df` on the x-axis and every column on the y-axis in a list. This process repeats itself for every column in `df`.

The result from `ManyScatterPlots()` is a list of lists, where each individual list contains many scatter plots. I've labeled both the list of lists and the individual plots to make it easier to find what you're looking for later on.

[image: Crappy screenshot]

```
# load necessary package -----
library(tidyverse)

# create a function that makes one scatter plot
ScatterPlot <- function(df, x, y) {
  # Input: 
  #     df: a data frame
  #     x: a column from df in the form of a character vector
  #     y: a column from df in the form of a character vector
  #
  # Output:
  #     a ggplot2 plot
  require(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = get(x), y = get(y))) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab(x) +
    ylab(y) +
    labs(title = paste0(y, " as explained by ", x))
}

# create a function that plots one ScatterPlot() for every possible column combination  -------
ManyScatterPlots <- function(df) {
  # Input: 
  #     df: a data frame
  #
  # Output:
  #     a list of ggplot2 plots from ScatterPlot()
  require(magrittr)
  require(purrr)

  # for each column in df
  # create an individual scatter plot for that column on the x-axis
  # and every column on the y-axis
  colnames(df) %>%
    map(.f = function(i) 
      map(.x = colnames(df), .f = function(j)
        ScatterPlot(df = df, x = i, y = j)) %>%
        # to help identify the individual plots for that particular column
        # label the plots inside the list
        purrr::set_names(nm = paste0(colnames(df)
                                     , " as explained by "
                                     , i))) %>%
    # to help identify the list of plots for each particular column
    # label the plots inside the list
    purrr::set_names(nm = colnames(df))
}

# use ManyScatterPlots() -----
many.plots <- ManyScatterPlots(df = mtcars)

# view results ---
names(many.plots)           # a list of lists
map(.x = many.plots, names) # a list of individual scatter plots
many.plots$disp$`hp as explained by disp`
many.plots$drat$`hp as explained by drat`
many.plots$hp$`qsec as explained by hp`

# end of script #
```