# Creating multiple plots in ggplot from a dataf rame with titles corresponding to the row names

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtitle

I am trying to create multiple scatter plot graphs in ggplot that have the same structure but I want to have the respective name of the rows in the column. I need them to be separate (and therefore not use facet_wrap) because in a later step I use grid_arrange to arrange different combinations of the graphs onto a single layout.

```
ggplot(data = check1, mapping = aes(x = log10(conc), y = data, color = Sample.Data.Type)) +
labs(x = "Concentration (Log(uM))", y = "Response (%)") +
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12), legend.title = element_blank())+
ggtitle(ptitle) + 
geom_line(aes(linetype = Sample.Data.Type)) 
geom_point()
```

Because of this, I need to separate names for each plot that reflect the different row name being plotted. Below is sample code, I tried to pull all the row names in a separate vector and tried to paste on the respective graphs. But It is pulling random row names and pasting it in the graph.

```
loop.list <- c(d3$Name)
for (Name in loop.list) {
col <- grep( paste0("Chemical", Name), colnames(d3) )
ptitle <- paste0("Chemical", Name)
}
```

Is there any simple way to just add the rowname as the plot title, for which it is being plot? I am pretty new to R, so any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Without the data it is difficult to make suggestions but it seems there is a pretty comprehensive solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434628/creating-multiple-ggplots-with-dplyr

Comment: Hi Novica, Thanks for the suggestion. It worked :)