# Create customized plotting function and run it with dynamic parameters using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, patch

Edited code for example from [this link](https://statisticsglobe.com/patchwork-r-package), I hope to convert it to a customized function and could easily apply it to new dataframes and arguments with similar formats:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Create ggplot2 scatterplot
p1 <- ggplot(iris,               
               aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                   y = Sepal.Width,
                   col = Species)) +
  geom_point()
p1
# Create ggplot2 barchart
p2 <- ggplot(iris,               
               aes(x = Species,
                   y = Sepal.Width,
                   fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p2

# Create ggplot2 boxplot
p3 <- ggplot(iris,
               aes(x = Species,
                   y = Sepal.Width,
                   col = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()
p3

# Create plot composition
p <- (p1 + p2) / p3
# Draw plot composition
p
```

Out:

[image]

Using code below, I create 3 samples, set `p1`, `p2` and `p3`'s parameters for `df1`, `df2`, `df3` respectively:

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- slice_sample(iris, n = 10)
df2 <- slice_sample(iris, n = 10)
df3 <- slice_sample(iris, n = 10)

# to set df1's and arguments (seems not good enough to store parameters, maybe I need to save it as config or ymal file?)
df1_plot1_param <- c(df='df1', x='Petal.Width', y='Sepal.Width', col='Species')
df1_plot2_param <- c(df='df1', x='Petal.Length', y='Sepal.Width', fill='Species')
df1_plot3_param <- c(df='df1', x='Sepal.Width', y='Petal.Width', col='Species')

# to set df2's arguments
df2_plot1_param <- c(df='df2', x='Sepal.Length', y='Sepal.Width', col='Species')
df2_plot2_param <- c(df='df2', x='Petal.Length', y='Sepal.Width', fill='Species')
df2_plot3_param <- c(df='df2', x='Sepal.Length', y='Petal.Width', col='Species')

# to set df3's arguments
df3_plot1_param <- c(df='df3', x='Sepal.Length', y='Sepal.Width', col='Species')
df3_plot2_param <- c(df='df3', x='Petal.Length', y='Sepal.Width', fill='Species')
df3_plot3_param <- c(df='df3', x='Sepal.Length', y='Petal.Width', col='Species')

for i in c(df1's params, df2's params, df3's params):
  purrr:map(plot_func(df{i}_param))
```

The final result will be 3 plots for `df`s with parameters pre-defined.

But I don't know how to make the whole code work out, thanks for your help at advance, thanks a lot.

**Reference links:**

[Creating multiple ggplots with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434628/creating-multiple-ggplots-with-dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. You can specify the X/Y and the grouping etc in the function.

EDIT: added dataframe as argument to function per the question

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- slice_sample(iris, n = 10)


library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
    
my_plot = function(DF=df, X="", Y="", GROUP=""){
  
  # Create ggplot2 scatterplot
  p1 <- ggplot(DF,               
               aes(x = .data[[X]],
                   y = .data[[Y]],
                   col = Species)) +
    geom_point()
  p1
  # Create ggplot2 barchart
  p2 <- ggplot(DF,               
               aes(x = .data[[GROUP]],
                   y = .data[[Y]],
                   fill = .data[[GROUP]])) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  p2
  
  # Create ggplot2 boxplot
  p3 <- ggplot(DF,
               aes(x = .data[[GROUP]],
                   y = .data[[Y]],
                   col = .data[[GROUP]])) +
    geom_boxplot()
  p3
  
  # Create plot composition
  p <- (p1 + p2) / p3
  # Draw plot composition
  return(p)
  
}

test = my_plot(DF=iris, X= "Sepal.Length",Y = "Sepal.Width", GROUP="Species")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, please note parameter of x, y are not always same for `p1`, `p2` and `p3` for same dataframe.

Comment: No worries. In that case, you could probably just run the function three different times for each dataframe (much like how you created the arguments for each dataframe). Should achieve what you want. Might be an easier way of course, but yeah...

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify multiple X and Y parameters if you want more flexibility. e.g Xp1, Xp2 and Xp3 instead of just X. Should also achieve what you want.

Comment: I'll try the way you mentioned, thanks for helping me at weekend.

Comment: No worries. Hope it was helpful/useful :)